# Vue error for pagination: response is not defined

Tags: ajax, laravel, vue.js, pagination, axios

I keep getting this Vue error: **"ReferenceError: response is not defined"** but when I check in the console, the data is all there.

[image: Console Picture]

I intend to use the data from the response to make pagination. Thanks in advance.

**Methods**

```
getAllUserData(){
    let $this=this;
    axios.get('api/members/getAllMembersData').then(response=>this.members=response.data.data);
    $this.makePagination(response.meta,response.links);
},

makePagination(meta,links){
    let pagination={
    current_page:meta.current_page,
    last_page:meta.last_page,
    next_page_url:links.next,
    prev_page_url:links.prev
    }
    this.pagination = pagination;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your response is still inside the axios get method, therefore the makePagination function has to be called inside axios method as well (inside .then())

```
getAllUserData(){
    let $this=this;
    axios.get('api/members/getAllMembersData').then(response=>
    this.members=response.data.data
    $this.makePagination(response.data.meta,response.data.links);
},

makePagination(meta,links){
    let pagination={
    current_page:meta.current_page,
    last_page:meta.last_page,
    next_page_url:links.next,
    prev_page_url:links.prev
    }
    this.pagination = pagination;
}
```

Comment: thanks. now i got a new error TypeError: Cannot read property 'current_page' of undefined

Comment: to get the value of the response data. it should be
    $this.makePagination(response.data.meta, response.data.links)

Answer (score 0):

`axios.get()` is an async function. The code that follows this function will not be executed after the ajax request completes, but long before that. Because of this, the variable `response` does not exist yet.

All code that has to be executed when the ajax call completes has to be put in the `.then()` function of the call.

```
getAllUserData(){
    axios.get('api/members/getAllMembersData').then(response => {
        this.members = response.data.data;
        this.makePagination(response.data.meta, response.data.links);
    });
},
```

Comment: thanks. now i got a new error  TypeError: Cannot read property 'current_page' of undefined

Comment: `response` had to be `response.data`, I updated my answer

Comment: If this answer helped you, consider marking it as the answer to your question so other users might find this as well in the future.